# Tools in Visual Studio to analyze freezing problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, analysis, freeze

I am working on an application that is experiencing some freezing problems. I am not the author of the program myself and the codebase is quite large.

The GUI of the program freezes periodically (for a secod or two) and, since I'm not that familiar with the code, I find it hard to track the source of the freezing problem. Thus i wonder if there is an easy way to detect the source of the problem in Visual Studio 2015 with some kind of analysis tool?

The application is a winforms app written in C# with .net 4.0.

/Karra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you have in the menu bar the point *"Analyze"*. Click there and select *"Start Performance Analyze **Paused**"*. Now bring your application to that point where the freeze occur. When you expect the freeze to happen within the next moments just start the analyzing and stop it right after the freeze has gone. Within the report you should hopefully see now who takes the most time and that is maybe your root cause.

I know this sounds a little bit messy and you have to fiddle around to really get the correct performance spot, but IMHO this is the best way if you are working with an unknown codebase.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.